# Reading small int with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Is there a way to read a small int (i.e. 1-byte int of range -128..127) using `scanf`? Consider this code:

```
char x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

The program will read an int, most probably 4 bytes, and try to write it at the address of x, thus violating the 3 bytes which come in the memory after this address.

I know there is a modifier for short int (`%h`), but I haven't heard about one for small int (`char`) ?

Comment: What language? Exactly? C and C++ are different, and both have variants.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanf("%d", char*) - char-as-int format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036396/scanfd-char-char-as-int-format-string) or [ANSI C (ISO C90): Can scanf read/accept an unsigned char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231056/ansi-c-iso-c90-can-scanf-read-accept-an-unsigned-char)

Comment: Oops, good catch, I meant to remove the `C++` tag.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why? How do you know the OP isn't writing C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` needs `"%hhd"` format string to read into a `char`.

Comment: I don't think that's standard, is it?

Comment: Strange, then, that C++'s `num_get` (which otherwise follows `scanf`'s format flag specification) does _not_ support it

Comment: I wonder if `num_get` gets used to parse `char` at all. Since `istream& operator>>(istream&, char&)` reads a symbol (not a digit) and stores its code in `char`.